# How to use shouldComponentUpdate with React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, react-hooks

I've been reading these links:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-shouldcomponentupdate
https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/23/react-v-16-6.html

In the first link it says (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#from-classes-to-hooks):

> shouldComponentUpdate: See React.memo

The second link also states that:

Class components can bail out from rendering when their input props are the same using PureComponent or shouldComponentUpdate. Now you can do the same with function components by wrapping them in React.memo.

---

What is desired:

I want Modal to render only when the Modal is visible (managed by this.props.show)

For class component:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return nextProps.show !== this.props.show;
}
```

How can I use `memo` instead in a functional component - here, in Modal.jsx?

---

The related code:

Functional component Modal.jsx (I don't know how to check for props.show)

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import styles from './Modal.module.css';
import BackDrop from '../BackDrop/BackDrop';

const Modal = React.memo(props => {
  useEffect(() => console.log('it did update'));

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <BackDrop show={props.show} clicked={props.modalClosed} />
      <div
        className={styles.Modal}
        style={{
          transform: props.show ? 'translateY(0)' : 'translateY(-100vh)',
          opacity: props.show ? '1' : '0'
        }}>
        {props.children}
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
});

export default Modal;
```

The part of class component PizzaMaker jsx that renders Modal:

```
 return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Modal show={this.state.purchasing} modalClosed={this.purchaseCancel}>
          <OrderSummary
            ingredients={this.state.ingredients}
            purchaseCancelled={this.purchaseCancel}
            purchaseContinued={this.purchaseContinue}
            price={this.state.totalPrice}
          />
        </Modal>
        ...
      </React.Fragment>
    );
```

Comment: with `React.memo`, the component will only rerenders if props change, so this is basically what you want

Comment: I only want it to rerender when ```props.show``` is true, not ```props``` itself. Because as long as it's invisible, to increase its performance. It gets visible by clicking 'order now' button which triggers props.show to be true and bring up the order summary, that resides within Modal, to be visible.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Here is the [documentation for React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)

You can pass a function to control the comparison :

```
const Modal = React.memo(
  props => {...},
  (prevProps, nextProps) => prevProps.show === nextProps.show
);
```

when the function returns `true`, the component will not be re-rendered

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks for the KISS approach. And it's exactly what I wanted to know about memo.

Comment: what is different between react.memo and useMemo() in react hooks ?

Comment: React.memo is used to prevent rendering of a functional component, useMemo is a hook to prevent recomputing a value inside a functional component

Comment: Is this the right answer? Because apparently React.memo cannot be counted on like shouldComponentUpdate. From the docs: "This method only exists as a performance optimization. Do not rely on it to “prevent” a render, as this can lead to bugs."

Comment: @JBaczuk as you said it seems to be used for performance boost only, so the component might be re-rendered even if the function returns true, strange behavior :(

Comment: @OlivierBoissé I guess that same warning is given in the docs for shouldComponentUpdate so the answer is correct. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: how can you check the state with this implement?...

Answer (score 13):

Also you can use in export statement like:

```
export default memo(Modal, (prevProps, nextProps) => prevProps.show === nextProps.show) ;
```

Comment: it's not prevState and nextState, It's a prop (prevProps, nextProps).

Comment: Elegant, exactly wanted this!