# Avoid re-rendering children if a parent container changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am designing a modal system where a modal can be displayed on a drawer (for smallscreens) or as a modal window.

I created a Wrapper component that wraps its children with either of those components, depending on the screen size:

```
const Wrapper: React.FunctionComponent<any> = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  let WrapperComponent: React.FunctionComponent

  const modalType = useModalType()

  if (modalType === "drawer") {
    WrapperComponent = MobileDrawer
  } else {
    WrapperComponent = ModalContainer
  }

  return <WrapperComponent {...props}>{children}</WrapperComponent>
}
```

When I change the window size, `useModalType` changes and `Wrapper` re-renders with the correct wrapper, as expected. But the children component are re-rendered completely, loosing their own states.

Is it any way to memoize the children so they are kept the same when the wrapper component changes?

Comment: Have you looked into `shouldComponentUpdate()`? You could use it in the child components to keep them from re-rendering.

Comment: I would prefer to not use class-based components here, so the solution is probably involving a `useMemo` hook, but I am not sure how…

Comment: I guess [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56297625/12461764) is what you're looking for.

Comment: can i see the code for `useModalType`?

Comment: Can you share the props?

Comment: Well, I tried `React.memo` and `useMemo` in various ways but didn't work out.
If you save the children state in an upper `ModalProvider` or Redux it can workout but it's not elegant solution imo. here's my playground https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-ardinghelli-xi7qr

Comment: more stuff i found related to the topic https://gist.github.com/slikts/e224b924612d53c1b61f359cfb962c06

Comment: @Lelouch it basically reads from a context

Comment: the way i see it, it could be the `modalType` that needs to be memoized so can we please see the code for it?

Comment: @Lelouch, Check out my code playground.just drag the provider state to the counter

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your child component in a `React.memo`

e.g.

```
const MyComponent = React.memo(function MyComponent(props) {
  /* only rerenders if props change */
});
```

You'll find more here: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/23/react-v-16-6.html#reactmemo

Your component will only re-render if it's props change...

Comment: As far as I understand what is happening, as my wrapper component changes, React trashes my children component in the virtual DOM and creates a new one under the new wrapper component, so memoization does not work

Comment: @Renaud Chaput I think it's exactly what happens, since the component changes the the whole tree unmounts. The only solution is what I suggested in the comments, a lifted state(`SomeProvider` or Redux).very interesting case thanks.