# How to use shouldComponentUpdate() to control state from re-rendering a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I add `shouldComponentUpdate()` to my particular use case. A hover effect state sets off a re-render to a particular component that I don't want rendered again. I'm trying to grasp on how to correctly use it for my case below:

(Hover over any card, you will see how `<MiniGraphs>` component animates itself again during hover statechange)
https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-microservice-gsyxw?file=/src/App.js:2237-2384

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong, but my VScode is this showing me syntax errors?
The actionButton state declares if the user is hovering over a `<Card>`. If it's true, then I don't want  component re-rendered.

```
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        actionButton: false
    });

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
   /// Getting syntax errors for this code, not sure what to put in here...
    
 }
```

EDIT:
There’s a vote going on to close this question but the referred stackoverflow link doesn’t talk about this on the  memo docs:

“ Do not rely on it to “prevent” a render, as this can lead to bugs.”

Comment: `shouldComponentUpdate` is a method in class components. Your use of `useState` indicates a function component. You can't mix these directly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use shouldComponentUpdate with React Hooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56297351/how-to-use-shouldcomponentupdate-with-react-hooks)

Comment: Oh okay, what should I look at for the functional comp replacement?

Comment: Yes that helps me for now

Comment: Directly taken from the React docs about `memo`:      `Do not rely on it to “prevent” a render, as this can lead to bugs.`

Comment: Right, and the same applies to `shouldComponentUpdate`. You use it as a performance optimisation to stop unnecessary rerenders, but this "stopping" is not guaranteed so you shouldn't do this if a rerender taking place will actually cause a bug. (If the latter then you need to fix the bug elsewhere.)