# Nextjs Optimization scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

I'm trying to get the scrolling position. My code is working fine, but every time I scroll the function always rerenders the React component. I know the reason: every time I scroll I update the scroll position within the component's state.

```js
export function Home() {
    const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleScroll = () => {
            setScrollPosition(window.scrollY);
        };
        handleScroll();
        window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
        };
    }, []);

    console.log('render function')

    return null
}
```

Is there a way to optimize this code?

Comment: Try throttling/debouncing your handler, it will reduce some re-renders. You can also give this a look: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-shouldcomponentupdate Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56297625/11613622, https://stackoverflow.com/q/54666401/11613622

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using this custom hook. I used it and it's super optimized.
https://github.com/n8tb1t/use-scroll-position